# add different styles when text wraps to next line

Tags: css, responsive

I have a div with a small heading - just two words.

When I resize da browser the text wraps and the last word goes to the next line.

I want to display different styles to the last word only when it goes to the next line. For instance: font-weight:normal instead of being bold.

Is that possible only with css?

Comment: You have two problem here :

1. Do you know, with media queries, **when** the last word goes to the next line ? 
If no, it will be impossible to add style at the right moment.

2. There is no `:last-word` pseudo element in css
You can try to use thing like http://letteringjs.com/ but there is no native way in css.

Comment: this is dynamic text. And it can be bigger or smaller for different language, so I believe that media queries is not the perfect solution. Thanks

Comment: You should use some javascript in this case. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the`::first-line` pseudo element for this.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line):

> The ::first-line CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first line
>   of a block-level element. Note that the length of the first line
>   depends on many factors, including the width of the element, the width
>   of the document, and the font size of the text.

```css
section {
  width: 10%;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2:first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Some heading</h2>
</section>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/zjQRPZ) (resize to see the effect)

Comment: Awesome. Just what I was looking for. Didn't remeber this pseudo-elemement

Answer (score 0):

Since your content is more dynamic, you may need to use Javascript to accomplish this. An event listener on page resize that checks the height of your heading div and adjusts a span containing the second word should do the trick.

```
window.onresize = function(){
 document.getElementById('last_word').style.font-weight = 'normal';
};
```

<strike>If your page content is fairly static, you could probably get away with using a css media query. I don't know of any way to have css grab the second word in a div, but if you put the second word in a span you could do something like this:</strike>

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
 #header_id>span {
  font-weight: normal;
 }
}
```

Of course, replacing the 700px with whatever width you find triggers the content to word wrap.

Comment: I mentioned only with css

Comment: And I've answered: I'm pretty sure it's not possible, just as Clement mentioned in the comments. If it is in fact possible, I'd be delighted to be proven wrong and learn something new.

Comment: Another thing that might perhaps work is to have a <br> tag inside the heading that is only shown on smaller screen sizes so that you can manually trigger word wrap at the same point for all your potential content. At that point the media query approach might work. Fine if you don't like this idea, just occurred to me as a possible option. :)